# Extend bit pattern to generic vector size in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

```
constant alternate_bits : std_logic_vector(C_BIT_SIZE-1 downto 0) := X;
```

What do I write in place of X to set it to an alternating pattern of bits, while keeping it generic and without getting upset if C_BIT_SIZE isn't even?

For example, if C_BIT_SIZE = 4 it should produce "1010" and if C_BIT_SIZE = 5 it should produce "01010".  (And it should work for any value of C_BIT_SIZE >= 1.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function can be used:

```
-- Returns std_logic_vector(BIT_SIZE-1 downto 0) with bits on even indexes
-- as '0' and bits on odd indexes as '1', e.g. 5 bit vector as "01010".
function alternate_fun(BIT_SIZE : natural) return std_logic_vector is
  variable res_v : std_logic_vector(BIT_SIZE - 1 downto 0);
begin
  res_v := (others => '0');
  for i in 1 to BIT_SIZE / 2 loop
    res_v(2 * i - 1) := '1';
  end loop;
  return res_v;
end function;
```

Comment: Looks like you snuck this one in while I was formatting my own answer :)  I like this one though since it avoids the conditional and is reusable for other sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that seems to do the trick but I'm interested in alternate tidier answers:

```
subtype data_vector is std_logic_vector(C_BIT_SIZE-1 downto 0);

function make_alternate_bits return data_vector is
    variable bits : data_vector;
begin
    for i in 0 to C_BIT_SIZE-1 loop
        if (i mod 2) = 0 then
            bits(i) := '0';
        else
            bits(i) := '1';
        end if;
    end loop;
    return bits;
end function;

constant alternate_bits : data_vector := make_alternate_bits;
```

Comment: And in VHDL-2008 you can reduce the if statement to `bits(i) := '0' when (i mod 2 = 0) else '1';`.

Comment: @MortenZdk unfortunatelly it's not supported by synthesis tools, at least not Quartus.